# Connect Sybase ASE Database to Xamarin Android App without web services

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, sybase, sap-ase

Is there a way to do this without web services? I was reading about jtds but i can't make it work throught "Android Java Binding Library".

Thanks!

Comment: Still recommend going through a web service: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15853367/jdbc-vs-web-service-for-android